# Loading Data from Hive to Pig Error while Dumping DataSet

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

`retail_db.categories` is having 58 rows

```
$pig -useHCatalog
grunt> pcategories = LOAD 'retail_db.categories' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
grunt>b = limit pcategories 100;
grunt>dump b;
```

Then **I am getting all the records**
But when **I am trying to dump original dataset**

```
grunt>dump pcategories;
```

Then I am getting **Error**

> 2018-04-15 16:27:46,444 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:46,723 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
>   - ObjectStore, initialize called 2018-04-15 16:27:47,170 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql - Using direct
>   SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL 2018-04-15 16:27:47,171 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore - Initialized ObjectStore
>   2018-04-15 16:27:47,171 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 2018-04-15 16:27:47,171 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck  2018-04-15 16:27:47,184 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_table :
>   db=retail_db tbl=categories 2018-04-15 16:27:47,184 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=retail_db
>   tbl=categories     2018-04-15 16:27:47,219 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,244 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 2018-04-15 16:27:47,244 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck  2018-04-15 16:27:47,247 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_table :
>   db=retail_db tbl=departments 2018-04-15 16:27:47,247 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=retail_db
>   tbl=departments    2018-04-15 16:27:47,261 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,284 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 2018-04-15 16:27:47,284 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck  2018-04-15 16:27:47,286 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_table :
>   db=retail_db tbl=categories 2018-04-15 16:27:47,286 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=retail_db
>   tbl=categories     2018-04-15 16:27:47,386 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,388 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState -
>   Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN 2018-04-15 16:27:47,397
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,397 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend -
>   SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,397 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer -
>   {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator,
>   GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter,
>   MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer,
>   PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer,
>   PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter,
>   StreamTypeCastInserter]} 2018-04-15 16:27:47,398 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler
>   - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false 2018-04-15 16:27:47,399 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size before optimization: 1 2018-04-15 16:27:47,399 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size after optimization: 1 2018-04-15 16:27:47,406 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,407 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy -
>   Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-04-15 16:27:47,409
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState -
>   Pig script settings are added to the job 2018-04-15 16:27:47,409
>   [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3 2018-04-15 16:27:47,435 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 2018-04-15 16:27:47,435 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases:
>   NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck  2018-04-15 16:27:47,437 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_table :
>   db=retail_db tbl=categories 2018-04-15 16:27:47,437 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit -
>   ugi=jay   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=retail_db
>   tbl=categories     2018-04-15 16:27:47,458 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated.
>   Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled 2018-04-15
>   16:27:47,458 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - This job cannot be converted run in-process 2018-04-15 16:27:48,419 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/hive-metastore-2.3.2.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp122824794/hive-metastore-2.3.2.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:48,608 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp1608619006/libthrift-0.9.3.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:49,708 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/hive-exec-2.3.2.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp1023486409/hive-exec-2.3.2.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:50,352 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/libfb303-0.9.3.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp-207303388/libfb303-0.9.3.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:51,375 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp120570913/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:51,497 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp1251741235/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:51,786 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/hive-hbase-handler-2.3.2.jar
>   to DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp1351750668/hive-hbase-handler-2.3.2.jar
>   2018-04-15 16:27:52,653 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig-0.17.0/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp1548980484/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:53,042 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-2.3.2.jar to DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp-2078279932/hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-2.3.2.jar
>   2018-04-15 16:27:53,197 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/pig-0.17.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp1231439146/automaton-1.11-8.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:53,875 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Added jar file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar to
>   DistributedCache through
>   /tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp970518288/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar 2018-04-15
>   16:27:53,900 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Setting up single store job 2018-04-15 16:27:53,920 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission. 2018-04-15 16:27:53,922 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting
>   to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-04-15 16:27:54,152
>   [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader -
>   Disabling Erasure Coding for path:
>   /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/jay/.staging/job_1523787662857_0004
>   2018-04-15 16:27:54,197 [JobControl] WARN 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.
>   User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
>   2018-04-15 16:27:54,232 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat - Total input files to
>   process : 1 2018-04-15 16:27:54,232 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total
>   input paths (combined) to process : 1 2018-04-15 16:27:54,631
>   [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number
>   of splits:1 2018-04-15 16:27:55,247 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job:
>   job_1523787662857_0004 2018-04-15 16:27:55,247 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Executing with tokens: []
>   2018-04-15 16:27:55,253 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner - Job jar is not present. Not
>   adding any jar to the list of resources. 2018-04-15 16:27:55,503
>   [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted
>   application application_1523787662857_0004 2018-04-15 16:27:55,733
>   [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track
>   the job:
>   http://jay-Lenovo-Z50-70:8088/proxy/application_1523787662857_0004/
>   2018-04-15 16:27:55,733 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - HadoopJobId: job_1523787662857_0004 2018-04-15 16:27:55,733 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Processing aliases pcategories 2018-04-15 16:27:55,733 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - detailed locations: M: pcategories[3,14] C:  R:  2018-04-15 16:27:55,877 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 0% complete 2018-04-15 16:27:55,877 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Running jobs are [job_1523787662857_0004] 2018-04-15 16:28:27,422 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure. 2018-04-15 16:28:27,422 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job job_1523787662857_0004 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs 2018-04-15 16:28:27,422 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete 2018-04-15 16:28:27,424 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager
>   at /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-04-15 16:28:27,580 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager
>   at /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-04-15 16:28:27,827 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce
>   job(s) failed! 2018-04-15 16:28:27,827 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script
>   Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
>   3.0.0 0.17.0  jay 2018-04-15 16:27:47 2018-04-15 16:28:27 UNKNOWN
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   job_1523787662857_0004    pcategories MAP_ONLY    Message: Job
>   failed!   hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp-83503168,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from "retail_db.categories"
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in
>   "hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp-1113251818/tmp-83503168"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1523787662857_0004
>
> 2018-04-15 16:28:27,828 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed! 2018-04-15 16:28:27,836 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator
>   for alias pcategories Details at logfile:
>   /home/jay/pig_1523787729987.log

```
AM Container for appattempt_1523799060075_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-04-15 19:02:58.344]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1523799060075_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
[2018-04-15 19:02:58.348]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[2018-04-15 19:02:58.348]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://jay-Lenovo-Z50-70:8088/cluster/app/application_1523799060075_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.  this what get after clicking the link
```

Comment: Where it says `The url to track the job`... Your actual errors output should exist there in YARN

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. I ran below commands

```
$pig -useHCatalog
grunt> pcategories = LOAD 'hive_testing.address' USINGorg.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
grunt>dump pcategories
```

Here i have created a dummy address table in my database

Output

(101,india,xxx)

So the issue could be with your dataset and not with the commands you are running.

Comment: Read the question properly and error message I know my commands are correct but I don't know why my DUMP is not working

Comment: Your question was that it's giving error while dumping the actual dataset. So that's what I did, I dump the actual dataset and it is working fine. Can you try with some other table and dump the original dataset

Comment: I tried same problem I think it's because of my configurations